# Display JSON Array Data Returned from Controller in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action method in my controller as;

```
public ActionResult IndexWithJson(int Id, int? page)
{
    int pageSize = 2;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    using (var adsRepo = new AdvertisementRepository())
    {
        if (Id > 0)
        {
            return Json(new{
                Data = adsRepo.GetAdvertisementBySubCategoryId(Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("404");
        }

    }
}
```

the result output in the browser is;
[image]
As you can see in the picture, I have an wrap up the data (in controller as well) with an object called "Data".
Now when I call this using jQuery like this;

```
var serviceBase = "/catalog/";

$.ajax({
    url: serviceBase + 'IndexWithJson',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType:'json',
    data: { Id: categoryId, page: page },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.Title);
    }
});
```

**I see null in alert box.** 
What is the problem here? 
**How do I actually display just one property (see the picture fro properties) in alert box.** 
**Is my dataType attribute right in jQuery ajax function? (I guess it should be JSONP**

Comment: what's the url of your page (where the javascript is) and the url of your mvc site ? Are they on the same domain + port ?

Comment: yeah, on the same doamin/site.

Comment: see the     var serviceBase = "/catalog/";
i updated the question

Comment: It looks like it's an object with the property Data which is an array of objects. Try `data.Data[0].Title`.

Comment: Try to stringify the whole return to see what's in: alert(JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: i used the stringfy before, and gives me error

Comment: @Sam, you were right, this data.Data[0].Title works for me

Comment: i should notice this becuase i wrap up the data with object `Data`, and it's an array as well. So data.Data[0].Title works

Comment: @Sam, post your answer, so i could mark it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
data.Data[0].Title
```

This should be working

Comment: yeah this works, coz i was wrapping up everything in `Data`. And also it's an array. So, i should tried this.

Comment: no, just custom jquery. i used that before but now trying to do some custom coding. Anyway, thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alert(data[0].Title)
```

It's an array.

To display all you could do something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('#somediv').append(value.Title);
});
```

Comment: TypeError: data[0] is undefined

Comment: and if you inspect data in chrome? Try putting a debugger; statement in your succes function and inspect it with firebug or chrome.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting me. Was my answer that bad?

Comment: if you have succes: function(data) then data is NOT with an uppercase D. Mo##$ns

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use JSON.stringify to send arguments(in your ajax call to controller. Something like 
 data: JSON.stringify({ Id: categoryId, page: page }), 
 Are you getting Id and page values at controller end properly?  I think your result of ajax call is coming as null i.e.  data = null at client end.

Comment: this is working fine because see the pciture. it's returning the data

Comment: Is it the complete string that you get in output? Don't you see it as JSON object in debugger mode?

Comment: the prob is sovled. i should use this data.Data[0].Title