# Display list data using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the following structure:

1. WebService - get the data from database and return the list of
   persons
2. ASP.NET MVC application - uses web service from 1).

There's a method in HomeControler:

```
public JsonResult GetDbData()
{
    WebService1SoapClient client = new WebService1SoapClient();
    List<Person> lstPersons = client.GetPersons();

    return Json(lstPersons, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'd like to display the list of persons in Index.cshtml view using jQuery Ajax call in this manner:

```
<div>
    <div id="div3">Database data.</div>
</div>

<input id="btnGetDBData" type="button" value="GetDBData" />

$('#btnGetDBData').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetDbData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#div3").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
});
```

But, it's not working.

I'm new in jQuery and need some kind of table or template or something like repeater that can display the list or table structure.

The Person class looks as following:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to display the list of persons in Html table.

Comment: you are returning an array, you should try loop or access it using an array index => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848183/display-json-array-data-returned-from-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: make a partial view, showing the list and return it from your action.

Comment: Everything should be in JavaScript (jQuery).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why you are setting content of `div3` with `.html`?

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#div3").html('');
    var div3Content = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
       div3Content += '<p>' + data[i].Name + '</p>'; // if Name is property of your Person object
    }
    $("#div3").append(div3Content);
},
```

In this way, `Person` names will be added into `div3` as `<p>` tag

Comment: @FSou1: typo mistake, thanks for pointing that out - corrected

Comment: `$("#div3").html('');` will clear div in every iteration and only last data will be displayed

Comment: @Satpal: already updated. it'll clear `div3` after each call to server, and than update the content as per the result

Comment: I don't really need div. It could be Html table.

Comment: @tesicg: in that case, instead of `$("#div3").append('<p>'+data[i].Name+'</p>');`, you'll just have to append row in `table` - `$("#div3").append('<tr><td>'+data[i].Name+'</td></tr>');`

Comment: @Paritosh, actually it's not a good practice to loop through each item and appended to DOM, i would actually make an `HTML` string and then append it to the DOM

Answer (score 2):

In your `data` variable in `success` method you have an array of your data and you have to draw it manually

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("#div3").append(value.Id + '|' + value.FirstName + '|' + value.LastName);
    });
}
```

Comment: I know that and I ask for help how to do that.

Comment: You have `data` array in function, where each element is an object (isn't it?) So you could make it with jQuery

Comment: We don't how you would like to display it and what properties do you have

Comment: Yes. Please, take a look at the original post. There are required details.

Comment: For example, you could use it like this,- you have to decide your own output format

Answer (score 0):

`$('#div3').html(data)` sets the HTML literally to what is found in data. However, after your jQuery call `data` contains an array of objects, not HTML. You first need to define what the HTML should look like. - Do you want it as a unordered list, a table, an array of nice-looking tiles, ...?

For rendering HTML from data I suggest you also consider templating and/or data-binding libraries such as, e.g. [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) which allows you to define the template in HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: persons">
    <li data-bind="text: LastName"></li>
</ul>
```

and your jQuery ajax success callback:

```
success: function (data) {
    ko.applyBindings({ persons: data });
}
```

The knockout foreach binding as above is kind of a repeater as you asked for.

*Update*: If you want a table the knockout template simply changes to something like:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Full Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: persons">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: FirstName() + ' ' + LastName()"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes. Please, take a look at the original post. There are required details.

Comment: @tesicg: I have updated my answer - you can use foreach like a repeater, i.e. you can do whatever you like with it, it does not need to be either of a table or a list. The snipped above only serves as an example.